# Oxidation number vs charge?

Tags: oxidation-state, reduction-potential, formal-charge

From what I understand:

*oxidation numbers: are the "act" of electrons moving

while

*charge: is what the atom "wants" to do with its electrons.

-

Can anyone please clear up the distinction between the two and when its appropriate to use one, the other, or both at the same time?

-

Is it that charge is only used for ions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an atom loses electrons, it develops a positive charge and becomes a cation. Likewise, if an atoms gains electrons, it develops a negative charge and becomes an anion.

"Charges only EXIST on IONS."

Covalent bonding rose the **oxidation number**.
We are aware that in a Covalent Bond sharing of electron takes place.
The more **electronegative** atom will take more bonding electrons and it will get a negative oxidation number (It depicts Anion).
Similarly less electronegative atom mimics a Cation.

In other words you can say Oxidation Numbers are ***fictional ionic charges***

Comment: Im guessing that means I need to use one or the other, never both at the same time?

Comment: Yes, electrovalent bonds carry Charge while covalent bonds carry Oxidation Numbers.